# How can I show that an image is selected or deselected in android?

Tags: java, android

I am new in android programming. I should first mention that I have no idea how to start to solve this problem.
PLEASE WATCH [THIS SHORT VIDEO](http://youtu.be/LhpfQGBvPJ8) TO FIND EXACTLY WHAT I NEED. WHEN THE USER CLICKS ON THE IMAGE, A BORDER AND A DARK RECTANGLE APPEARS BEHIND THE IMAGE. AND WHEN THE USER CLICKS SOMEWHERE ELSE (NOT ON THE IMAGE), THE BORDER AND THE RECTANGLE DISAPPEARS.
PLEASE HELP. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the right answer myself. I wrote it in another post. I put its link here maybe it would be a help for someone.
[How to select and deselect an image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29065332/how-to-select-and-deselect-an-image-in-android/30079971#30079971)

Answer (score 0):

Save the border image shown in btn_pressed in res -> drawable and the smiley image as btn_main_image

activity_main.xml :

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_default"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_main_image" />
```

btn_default.xml :  *specify the background of above button*

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/null"  android:state_focused="false"/>
```

Explaination :

> When user clicks on Smiley then Button view gets statePressed() callback which makes state_pressed as **true** so we need to set the frame image **btn_pressed** as background of simley at this time.
>
> When user clicks anywhere outside of button view, then focus is lost from button view and state_focused becomes **true** so we need to set nothing as backgeound  of smiley at this time so set **android:drawable="@drawable/null"**

Comment: Thank you Kushal for your answer. But it does not work. It does not do what I need.

Comment: Please specify what is your requirement exact

Comment: I have edited my question and sent two pictures.

Comment: Thank you Kushal. I know <selector>. But this is not the thing that I need.

Comment: I have edited my question. And I have uploaded a film to show what I mean. please help me. It is very important.

Comment: Thank you Kushal. But have you ever tested your answer?!! I see that in the <Button> attributes you have used android:background="@color/btn_default"  but in the btn_default.xml file you have drawable elements. and this not work. Please if I had a mistake, explain more.

Comment: So sorry but I have to say that it does not work.  Would you please try it? and if it works please send me the complete project by email. thanks a lot.