# How to select and deselect an image in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I am trying to write a project. In my project I can drag an image successfully.
[This is the PICTURE](http://8pic.ir/images/wi5td5tb5uih0jsmlqbl.png) and Here is my ViewOnTouchListener code:

```
package com.seifi.dragtestapplication;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
class ViewOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    Point pushPoint, closePoint;
    int lastImgLeft;
    int lastImgTop;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams viewLP;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams pushBtnLP;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams closeBtnLP;
    int lastPushBtnLeft, lastCloseBtnLeft;
    int lastPushBtnTop, lastCloseBtnTop;
    private View mPushView, mCloseView, mShadowView;

    ViewOnTouchListener(View mPushView, View mCloseView, View mShadowView) {
        this.mPushView = mPushView;
        this.mCloseView = mCloseView;
        this.mShadowView = mShadowView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (null == viewLP) {
                    viewLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                }
                if (null == pushBtnLP) {
                    pushBtnLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mPushView.getLayoutParams();
                }

                if (null == closeBtnLP) {
                    closeBtnLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mCloseView.getLayoutParams();
                }
                closePoint = getRawPoint(event);
                pushPoint = getRawPoint(event);
                lastImgLeft = viewLP.leftMargin;
                lastImgTop = viewLP.topMargin;
                lastPushBtnLeft = pushBtnLP.leftMargin;
                lastPushBtnTop = pushBtnLP.topMargin;

                lastCloseBtnLeft = closeBtnLP.leftMargin;
                lastCloseBtnTop = closeBtnLP.topMargin;
                (mShadowView).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_shadow_pressed);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Point newPoint = getRawPoint(event);
                float moveX = newPoint.x - pushPoint.x;
                float moveY = newPoint.y - pushPoint.y;

                viewLP.leftMargin = (int) (lastImgLeft + moveX);
                viewLP.topMargin = (int) (lastImgTop + moveY);
                view.setLayoutParams(viewLP);

                pushBtnLP.leftMargin = (int) (lastPushBtnLeft + moveX);
                pushBtnLP.topMargin = (int) (lastPushBtnTop + moveY);
                mPushView.setLayoutParams(pushBtnLP);

                closeBtnLP.leftMargin = (int) (lastCloseBtnLeft + moveX);
                closeBtnLP.topMargin = (int) (lastCloseBtnTop + moveY);
                mCloseView.setLayoutParams(closeBtnLP);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                (mShadowView).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_shadow);
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Point getRawPoint(MotionEvent event) {
        return new Point((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY());
    }
}
```

[Look at the PICTURE please](http://8pic.ir/images/wi5td5tb5uih0jsmlqbl.png)
and this is my DragView code:

```
package com.seifi.dragtestapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class DragView extends LinearLayout {
    private ImageView mView;
    private ImageView mPushView;
    private ImageView mCloseView;
    private View mShadowView;
    private float _1dp;
    private boolean mCenterInParent = true;
    private Drawable mImageDrawable, mPushImageDrawable, mCloseImageDrawable, mShadowImageDrawable;
    private float mImageHeight, mImageWidth, mPushImageHeight, mPushImageWidth, mCloseImageHeight, mCloseImageWidth, mShadowImageWidth, mShadowImageHeight;
    private int mLeft = 0, mTop = 0;


    public DragView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public DragView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DragView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this._1dp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        this.parseAttr(context, attrs);
        View mRoot = View.inflate(context, R.layout.drag_layout, null);
        addView(mRoot, -1, -1);
        mPushView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.push_view);
        mView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.view);
        mCloseView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.close_view);
        mShadowView = (View)mRoot.findViewById(R.id.shadowView);
        mView.setOnTouchListener(new ViewOnTouchListener(mPushView, mCloseView, mShadowView));
    }



    private void parseAttr(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (null == attrs) return;
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SingleFingerView);
        if (a != null) {
            int n = a.getIndexCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int attr = a.getIndex(i);
                if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_centerInParent) {
                    this.mCenterInParent = a.getBoolean(attr, true);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_image) {
                    this.mImageDrawable = a.getDrawable(attr);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_image_height) {
                    this.mImageHeight = a.getDimension(attr, 200 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_image_width) {
                    this.mImageWidth = a.getDimension(attr, 200 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_push_image) {
                    this.mPushImageDrawable = a.getDrawable(attr);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_push_image_width) {
                    this.mPushImageWidth = a.getDimension(attr, 30 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_push_image_height) {
                    this.mPushImageHeight = a.getDimension(attr, 30 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_left) {
                    this.mLeft = (int) a.getDimension(attr, 0 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_top) {
                    this.mTop = (int) a.getDimension(attr, 0 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_close_image) {
                    this.mCloseImageDrawable = a.getDrawable(attr);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_close_image_width) {
                    this.mCloseImageWidth = a.getDimension(attr, 30 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_close_image_height) {
                    this.mCloseImageHeight = a.getDimension(attr, 30 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_shadow_image) {
                    this.mShadowImageDrawable = a.getDrawable(attr);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_shadow_image_width) {
                    this.mShadowImageWidth = a.getDimension(attr, 200 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_shadow_image_height) {
                    this.mShadowImageHeight = a.getDimension(attr, 200 * _1dp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setViewToAttr(int pWidth, int pHeight) {
        if (null != mImageDrawable) {
            this.mView.setBackgroundDrawable(mImageDrawable);
        }
        if (null != mPushImageDrawable) {
            this.mPushView.setBackgroundDrawable(mPushImageDrawable);
        }

        if (null != mCloseImageDrawable) {
            this.mCloseView.setBackgroundDrawable(mCloseImageDrawable);
        }

        if (null != mShadowImageDrawable) {
            this.mShadowView.setBackgroundDrawable(mShadowImageDrawable);
        }

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams viewLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) this.mView.getLayoutParams();
        viewLP.width = (int) mImageWidth;
        viewLP.height = (int) mImageHeight;
        int left = 0, top = 0;
        if (mCenterInParent) {
            left = pWidth / 2 - viewLP.width / 2;
            top = pHeight / 2 - viewLP.height / 2;
        } else {
            if (mLeft > 0) left = mLeft;
            if (mTop > 0) top = mTop;
        }
        viewLP.leftMargin = left;
        viewLP.topMargin = top;
        this.mView.setLayoutParams(viewLP);
        this.mShadowView.setLayoutParams(viewLP);


        FrameLayout.LayoutParams pushViewLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mPushView.getLayoutParams();
        pushViewLP.width = (int) mPushImageWidth;
        pushViewLP.height = (int) mPushImageHeight;
        pushViewLP.leftMargin = (int) (viewLP.leftMargin + mImageWidth - mPushImageWidth / 2);
        pushViewLP.topMargin = (int) (viewLP.topMargin + mImageHeight - mPushImageHeight / 2);
        mPushView.setLayoutParams(pushViewLP);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams closeViewLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mCloseView.getLayoutParams();
        closeViewLP.width = (int) mCloseImageWidth;
        closeViewLP.height = (int) mCloseImageHeight;
        closeViewLP.leftMargin = (int) (viewLP.leftMargin - mCloseImageWidth / 2);
        closeViewLP.topMargin = (int) (viewLP.topMargin - mCloseImageHeight / 2);
        mCloseView.setLayoutParams(closeViewLP);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setParamsForView(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    private boolean hasSetParamsForView = false;

    private void setParamsForView(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
        if (null != layoutParams && !hasSetParamsForView) {
            System.out.println("");
            hasSetParamsForView = true;
            int width;
            if ((getLayoutParams().width == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)) {
                width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            } else {
                width = getLayoutParams().width;
            }
            int height;
            if ((getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)) {
                height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            } else {
                height = getLayoutParams().height;
            }
            setViewToAttr(width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

everything is OK. But my need is to do something that when the user clicks out of the image (sticker), the shadow and border disappear. And when the user clicks on the image again, they appear again.
I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the right answer. I think it can be helpful. So I share it.
First of all, I introduced a Rigion object like this in the DragView class:

```
public Region region;
```

then, I added a line to my constructor as this:

```
region = new Region(mView.getLeft(), mView.getTop(), mView.getRight(), mView.getBottom());
```

And then I added a method to my DragView.java file:

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){
        final int action = event.getAction();
        final int x = (int) event.getX();
        final int y = (int) event.getY();
        switch (action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (!region.contains(x, y)) {
                    mShadowView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                    mCloseView.setVisibility(GONE);
                    mPushView.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So the DragView.java fill will be as:

```
package com.seifi.dragtestapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class DragView extends LinearLayout {
    private ImageView mView;
    private ImageView mPushView;
    private ImageView mCloseView;
    private View mShadowView;
    private float _1dp;
    private boolean mCenterInParent = true;
    private Drawable mImageDrawable, mPushImageDrawable, mCloseImageDrawable, mShadowImageDrawable;
    private float mImageHeight, mImageWidth, mPushImageHeight, mPushImageWidth, mCloseImageHeight, mCloseImageWidth, mShadowImageWidth, mShadowImageHeight;
    private int mLeft = 0, mTop = 0;

    public Region region;


    public DragView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public DragView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DragView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this._1dp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        this.parseAttr(context, attrs);
        View mRoot = View.inflate(context, R.layout.drag_layout, null);
        addView(mRoot, -1, -1);
        mPushView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.push_view);
        mView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.view);
        mCloseView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.close_view);
        mShadowView = (View)mRoot.findViewById(R.id.shadowView);
        mView.setOnTouchListener(new ViewOnTouchListener(mPushView, mCloseView, mShadowView));

        region = new Region(mView.getLeft(), mView.getTop(), mView.getRight(), mView.getBottom());
    }



    private void parseAttr(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (null == attrs) return;
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SingleFingerView);
        if (a != null) {
            int n = a.getIndexCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int attr = a.getIndex(i);
                if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_centerInParent) {
                    this.mCenterInParent = a.getBoolean(attr, true);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_image) {
                    this.mImageDrawable = a.getDrawable(attr);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_image_height) {
                    this.mImageHeight = a.getDimension(attr, 200 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_image_width) {
                    this.mImageWidth = a.getDimension(attr, 200 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_push_image) {
                    this.mPushImageDrawable = a.getDrawable(attr);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_push_image_width) {
                    this.mPushImageWidth = a.getDimension(attr, 30 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_push_image_height) {
                    this.mPushImageHeight = a.getDimension(attr, 30 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_left) {
                    this.mLeft = (int) a.getDimension(attr, 0 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_top) {
                    this.mTop = (int) a.getDimension(attr, 0 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_close_image) {
                    this.mCloseImageDrawable = a.getDrawable(attr);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_close_image_width) {
                    this.mCloseImageWidth = a.getDimension(attr, 30 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_close_image_height) {
                    this.mCloseImageHeight = a.getDimension(attr, 30 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_shadow_image) {
                    this.mShadowImageDrawable = a.getDrawable(attr);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_shadow_image_width) {
                    this.mShadowImageWidth = a.getDimension(attr, 200 * _1dp);
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.SingleFingerView_shadow_image_height) {
                    this.mShadowImageHeight = a.getDimension(attr, 200 * _1dp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setViewToAttr(int pWidth, int pHeight) {
        if (null != mImageDrawable) {
            this.mView.setBackgroundDrawable(mImageDrawable);
        }
        if (null != mPushImageDrawable) {
            this.mPushView.setBackgroundDrawable(mPushImageDrawable);
        }

        if (null != mCloseImageDrawable) {
            this.mCloseView.setBackgroundDrawable(mCloseImageDrawable);
        }

        if (null != mShadowImageDrawable) {
            this.mShadowView.setBackgroundDrawable(mShadowImageDrawable);
        }

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams viewLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) this.mView.getLayoutParams();
        viewLP.width = (int) mImageWidth;
        viewLP.height = (int) mImageHeight;
        int left = 0, top = 0;
        if (mCenterInParent) {
            left = pWidth / 2 - viewLP.width / 2;
            top = pHeight / 2 - viewLP.height / 2;
        } else {
            if (mLeft > 0) left = mLeft;
            if (mTop > 0) top = mTop;
        }
        viewLP.leftMargin = left;
        viewLP.topMargin = top;
        this.mView.setLayoutParams(viewLP);
        this.mShadowView.setLayoutParams(viewLP);


        FrameLayout.LayoutParams pushViewLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mPushView.getLayoutParams();
        pushViewLP.width = (int) mPushImageWidth;
        pushViewLP.height = (int) mPushImageHeight;
        pushViewLP.leftMargin = (int) (viewLP.leftMargin + mImageWidth - mPushImageWidth / 2);
        pushViewLP.topMargin = (int) (viewLP.topMargin + mImageHeight - mPushImageHeight / 2);
        mPushView.setLayoutParams(pushViewLP);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams closeViewLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mCloseView.getLayoutParams();
        closeViewLP.width = (int) mCloseImageWidth;
        closeViewLP.height = (int) mCloseImageHeight;
        closeViewLP.leftMargin = (int) (viewLP.leftMargin - mCloseImageWidth / 2);
        closeViewLP.topMargin = (int) (viewLP.topMargin - mCloseImageHeight / 2);
        mCloseView.setLayoutParams(closeViewLP);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setParamsForView(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    private boolean hasSetParamsForView = false;

    private void setParamsForView(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
        if (null != layoutParams && !hasSetParamsForView) {
            System.out.println("");
            hasSetParamsForView = true;
            int width;
            if ((getLayoutParams().width == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)) {
                width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            } else {
                width = getLayoutParams().width;
            }
            int height;
            if ((getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)) {
                height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            } else {
                height = getLayoutParams().height;
            }
            setViewToAttr(width, height);
        }
    }



    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){
        final int action = event.getAction();
        final int x = (int) event.getX();
        final int y = (int) event.getY();
        switch (action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (!region.contains(x, y)) {
                    mShadowView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                    mCloseView.setVisibility(GONE);
                    mPushView.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And at finally, we must add these lines into the ViewOnTouchListener.java file:

```
        mShadowView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mCloseView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mPushView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

So this file will be:

```
package com.seifi.dragtestapplication;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

class ViewOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    Point pushPoint, closePoint;
    int lastImgLeft;
    int lastImgTop;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams viewLP;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams pushBtnLP;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams closeBtnLP;
    int lastPushBtnLeft, lastCloseBtnLeft;
    int lastPushBtnTop, lastCloseBtnTop;
    private View mPushView, mCloseView, mShadowView;

    ViewOnTouchListener(View mPushView, View mCloseView, View mShadowView) {
        this.mPushView = mPushView;
        this.mCloseView = mCloseView;
        this.mShadowView = mShadowView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (null == viewLP) {
                    viewLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                }
                if (null == pushBtnLP) {
                    pushBtnLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mPushView.getLayoutParams();
                }

                if (null == closeBtnLP) {
                    closeBtnLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mCloseView.getLayoutParams();
                }
                closePoint = getRawPoint(event);
                pushPoint = getRawPoint(event);
                lastImgLeft = viewLP.leftMargin;
                lastImgTop = viewLP.topMargin;
                lastPushBtnLeft = pushBtnLP.leftMargin;
                lastPushBtnTop = pushBtnLP.topMargin;

                lastCloseBtnLeft = closeBtnLP.leftMargin;
                lastCloseBtnTop = closeBtnLP.topMargin;
                (mShadowView).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_shadow_pressed);

                mShadowView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCloseView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mPushView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Point newPoint = getRawPoint(event);
                float moveX = newPoint.x - pushPoint.x;
                float moveY = newPoint.y - pushPoint.y;

                viewLP.leftMargin = (int) (lastImgLeft + moveX);
                viewLP.topMargin = (int) (lastImgTop + moveY);
                view.setLayoutParams(viewLP);

                pushBtnLP.leftMargin = (int) (lastPushBtnLeft + moveX);
                pushBtnLP.topMargin = (int) (lastPushBtnTop + moveY);
                mPushView.setLayoutParams(pushBtnLP);

                closeBtnLP.leftMargin = (int) (lastCloseBtnLeft + moveX);
                closeBtnLP.topMargin = (int) (lastCloseBtnTop + moveY);
                mCloseView.setLayoutParams(closeBtnLP);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                (mShadowView).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_shadow);
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Point getRawPoint(MotionEvent event) {
        return new Point((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY());
    }
}
```

Now, every thing is O.K.
It works perfect. [LINK OF VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQUqCESF9_U)

Comment: Sorry, I edited the link. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: "ngoa" , the link does work perfectly. I have tested it several times. This is its URL : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQUqCESF9_U